# Handling Missing Key via HashMap in Rust

Tags: string, rust, reference, hashmap

I am trying to decode an alphanumeric string using this `HashMap` table. I create an iterator using `.chars()` and then map each result to the `HashMap`. However, if a character in my string is numeric, I want to return it's value (since it wouldn't be found in the `HashMap`, which only decodes alphabetical characters). I am trying to handle it using `.unwrap_or()` but not sure the best way to make the character reference into a u32 within the same line.

Example string below: "4S3BJ"
Desired Result: [4,2,3,2,1]

```
use std::collections::HashMap;


fn main() {

    let translit: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::from([
        ('A', 1),
        ('B', 2),
        ('C', 3),
        ('D', 4),
        ('E', 5),
        ('F', 6),
        ('G', 7),
        ('H', 8),
        ('J', 1),
        ('K', 2),
        ('L', 3),
        ('M', 4),
        ('N', 5),
        ('P', 7),
        ('R', 9),
        ('S', 2),
        ('T', 3),
        ('U', 4),
        ('V', 5),
        ('W', 6),
        ('X', 7),
        ('Y', 8),
        ('Z', 9)
    ]);
    let s = String::from("4S3BJ");

    // Goal is to take characters from s and transliterate the characters to u32
    let transliterated: Vec<u32> = s.chars()
                                    .map(|c| *translit.get(&c).unwrap_or(&0))
                                    .collect();

    dbg!(transliterated);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let transliterated: Option<Vec<u32>> = s.chars()
                                .map(|c|  translit.get(&c).cloned().or_else(|| c.to_digit(10) ))
                                .collect();
```

It will return `None` if input string contains characters that are not in the map or are not digits. If you want to return default value you can use `unwrap_or`

Comment: Thanks! Care to explain the answer a bit more? I'm trying to understand why we need the ```.cloned()```. Is this because in order to mutate a potential ```&c``` value via ```to_digit()```, we need to dereference the characters?

Comment: Also, not too familiar with ```Option``` yet. How can I get the result to still be a ```Vec<u32>```?

Comment: @Coldchain9 The `Option` will be equal to `None` only if some of your characters are not able to be decoded (because they are not alphanumeric). You can use [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html) to detect and handle this case.

Comment: @Coldchain9 map.get() returns Option<&u32>, cloned() function clones contents of the option to return Option<u32>.  Because the return type is Vec<u32> not Vec<&u32> you need to do this somewhere.

Comment: @Coldchain9 You can write let x = transliterated.unwrap() to get rid of it if you are sure it cannot be None. You can read this chapter if you want to learn more. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-00-enums.html